# Advices for adapting an old Tcl/Tk application to modern standards

Tags: widget, styles, themes, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm converting an old Tcl/Tk application (written 20 years ago...) and any advice on what to do and how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

For the moment, I could adapt the code and it works but it is a bit ugly (the look&feel is not very satisfactory in particular because the application should run on both Linux and MacOS).

Trying to improve this point, I discovered 2 important changes in Tk: the introduction of themed widgets and the grid geometry manager.

Q1) From a strict point of view of the Look&Feel, is it a "good idea" to switch to a grid approach (it is a big work)? Can I mix grid and pack (because for some dynamic GUI parts the pack approach is simpler) ?

For the look&feel, I have tried to use themed widgets (replacing label by ttk:label, ...) but it is not yet satisfactory.

For instance the application has a title region (which can contain several different titles depending on the menu options selected). Basically I created it with:

```
ttk::style theme use clam

ttk::frame .c -padding "4"
grid .c  -sticky nsew 

ttk::label .c.t -relief groove -borderwidth 4 -justify center -text \
    "this is a title.\nAnd its subtittle\nHow to increase line spacing ?\nWhat about font size ?"
grid .c.t
```

The title can be multiline (and can be modified with a `.c.t configure -text "new title"` several times). The result is

[image]

Q2) How can I increase the space between 2 lines? (and how can I increase the font size) ?

Q3) I saw a text widget, but I could not find a themed version of it? Did I missed something ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

q1) Yes, you can mix pack and grid as you see fit.  Just not within the same frame.  Some people like to use grid exclusively, others mix them.

There is a comparison of themes [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/48689).  I find that the 'arc' and 'clearlooks' themes look nice on Linux.  For Mac OS X, leave the theme
as the default 'aqua'.

q2) New fonts can be created with the [font](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/font.htm) command.  For the ttk widgets 
these can be applied (in most cases) with the [ttk::style](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_style.htm) command.

For `ttk::label`, the linespacing is set by whatever font is being displayed.
The `text` command will give you more control over linespacing.

```
package require Tk
ttk::style theme use clam

ttk::frame .c -padding "4"
grid .c  -sticky nsew

font create newfont
font configure newfont -size 13 

ttk::style configure New.TLabel \
    -font newfont \
    -justify left
ttk::label .c.t -relief groove -borderwidth 4 -text \
    "this is a\nmultiline text.\nHow to increase line spaceing ?" \
    -style New.TLabel
grid .c.t
```

q3) The `text` command does not have a corresponding ttk widget (nor does listbox).

Comment: The `text` widget is really complex, and how it displays is virtually entirely determined by its content. (The `canvas` is another.) You can do a few tricks with wrapping it inside a `ttk::frame` and configuration hackery to make things look like a ttk::text would… and that's got to be a lot easier than the huge amount of work in C to make a real one!

Comment: One can use `ttk::treeview` in place of `listbox`. And for `text` there's a nice idea about putting `text` into a ttk frame with themed border here: http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/14796